# GitHub cloning - unable to access attributes from another linux account

Tags: linux, git, github, permissions

I have a repository on GitHub. I tried to to connect to this repository from my laptop with Debian. I want to connect from one of my linux accounts: **php-ocsclient**. But I did not succeed.

The strange thing is that the error message said that there was no access to **/home/gameboy/.config/git/attributes**. Why does it need the access to another account?

I purged git  completelly from my laptop an reinstall but this strange thing remained.

```
php-ocsclient@localhost:~/public_html$ git clone https://github.com/trzczy/php-ocsclient.git
Cloning into 'php-ocsclient'...
remote: Counting objects: 47, done.
remote: Total 47 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 47
Unpacking objects: 100% (47/47), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
warning: unable to access '/home/gameboy/.config/git/attributes': Brak dostępu
php-ocsclient@localhost:~/public_html$
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any environment variables set like `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` or by the global configuration item `core.attributesFile`?

Comment: From https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes - `Attributes which should be version-controlled and distributed to other repositories (i.e., attributes of interest to all users) should go into .gitattributes files. Attributes that should affect all repositories for a single user should be placed in a file specified by the core.attributesFile configuration option (see git-config[1]). Its default value is $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/attributes. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is either not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/attributes is used instead.`

Comment: @Joe You were right. Thanks. Anyway I had to use ssh because of another problem: `Could not resolve host: github.com`.